# android notification under specific conditions

Tags: android, notifications

I’m making application that use notifications, I want to show notification at a specific interval "eg. from 15/4/2019 to 29/4/2019" and repeat it 3 times in day. I have searched a lot but I couldn’t find working solution.

Comment: Are you looking for how to display a notification? or want to setup an alarm to trigger the notification at the specified time?

Comment: I want to setup alarm at the specified time

Comment: "I have searched a lot but I couldn’t find working solution." – Please edit your question to explain why the solutions you found didn't work for you. Otherwise, you're very likely to just get repeats of those same solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to be note about setting up alarms in Android.

- Alarms are recommend for simple tasks (e.g. showing up reminders) - not for doing any intensive work like network access.
- When you setup an alarm, Android will automatically display a clock icon at the notification bar.

Anyways, below is some sample code to setup an alarm (copied from Android Developer Documentation) .

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

You can find more details about setting up alarms and various options at the following [**Link.**](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#java)

Incase you do need access network, you might need to look [**WorkManager**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this solution.